# Checking if the checkbox is checked :DOJO Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a check box defined in my page for which the code is as follows,

```
<li class="Checkbox"> 
             <input 
                 id="Flag1" 
                 onclick="obj(this);"
                 type="checkbox"
                 name="Flag1.CheckName" 
                 dojotype="rmt.YNCheckBox"
                  <c:if test="${depotVal.checkFlag}">checked</c:if> 
             /> 
        </li>
```

In my javascript, I am trying to check if the above checkbox is checked and only if it is checked I am continuing with the rest of the code.

I tried with the below code. It is not working and throwing an error at the end of page.

```
var chkbox1 = dijit.byId("Flag1");

alert(chkbox1.checked);  //returns true when checked and false when unchecked

if ((chkbox1.checked) || (chkbox1.checked == true)){
       ...
        }
```

Is there any other alternative ? How to make it work consistently? Also the above snippet does not work in Mozilla.

Comment: DOM properties have been solid since DOM 0. If the above "doesn't work", the issue is elsewhere. Reduce to a minimal example that still shows the behaviour and post that. Post the code received at the client, not server code.

Comment: please post working code

Answer (score 0):

Where is it throwing an error? Is `chkbox1` an actual dijit?

Should you be using the `domNode` of the dijit anyway?

```
chkbox1.domNode.checked
```

Comment: It is throwing an error in the next selection box after this check box.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't really help as we can't see all of your code. If `chkbox1` is a genuine dijit reference, then it should have a `domNode` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
var t = query(".dijitCheckBoxInput");
array.forEach(t, function(item){
    if (item.checked) {
        item.checked = false;
    }
});
```

However this won't uncheck the checkboxes it will just change their internal state. To uncheck them I set the innerHTML of their container to checkBoxContainer.innerHTML = ' '; Then I executed the function that drew the checkboxes originally.

You probably figured it out by now but I figured I'd post it for anyone else trying to to something similar.